# Is this prove correct?

Tags: continuity

I want to prove that the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$ is continuous for $x\geq 0$. I'm using the definition of continuity taking $\varepsilon > 0\:\:and\:\:\delta=\varepsilon\cdot(1+x)(1+c)$:

$$\left | f(x)-f(c)\right |=\left | \frac{x}{1+x}-\frac{c}{1+c} \right |=\left | \frac{x-c}{(1+x)\cdot (1+c)}\right |=  \frac{\delta }{(1+x)\cdot (1+c)} = \frac{\varepsilon \cdot (1+x)\cdot (1+c)}{(1+x)\cdot (1+c)}=\varepsilon $$
Does this prove that $f(x)$ is continuous? Thanks

EDIT:
$$\left | f(x)-f(c)\right |=\left | \frac{x}{1+x}-\frac{c}{1+c} \right |=\left | \frac{x-c}{(1+x)\cdot (1+c)}\right |=\left | \frac{1}{(1+x)(1+c)} \right |\cdot \left | x-c \right |\leq 1\cdot \left | x-c \right |\leq \delta =\varepsilon $$

Comment: Moreover, your function is not continuous at $x=1$

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks for the feedback. Is the edit correct?

Comment: @JaviBT Yes you can bound the fraction above by $1$ using $x,c\ge0$ and then use $\delta=\epsilon$ instead.

Comment: @PeterForeman Okay. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $f$ is continuous in $c$ you have to show that for an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta:=\delta(\varepsilon,c)$ such that 
$$ |f(x)-f(c)|\le \varepsilon,\; \forall x : |x-c|\le \delta$$

With $\delta:=\delta(\varepsilon,c)$ I want to express that $\delta$ may depend on $c$ and $\varepsilon$. It must not depend on $x$. You define delta as 
$$\varepsilon\cdot(1+x)(1+c)$$
which apparently depends on $x$. So this $\delta$ does not fulfill the requirements. But you have

$$\left | f(x)-f(c)\right |=\left | \frac{x}{1+x}-\frac{c}{1+c} \right |=\left | \frac{x-c}{(1+x)\cdot (1+c)}\right |\lt  \frac{\delta }{(1+x)\cdot (1+c)} \le \delta=\varepsilon$$ 
because $x\ge0$ and $c\ge 0$ and therefore $(1+x)\cdot(1+c)\ge 1$.